# Ubuntu 16.04 - Laptop with two Radeon cards. Currently getting into the system with nomodeset, but with limited resolution

Tags: 16.04, radeon

I have been hunting around for a solution to this issue for some time, and nothing I have found seems to have done the trick.

My two questions are:

1. Is there a workaround that will allow me full resolution?
2. Is there a distro similar to Ubuntu that has an easier time with older Radeon cards?

Here is the output of lshw -c video:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=256)      memory:f0300000-f033ffff

  *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0200000-f021ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0220000-f023ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu 16.10 solved it for me.
Starting with 16.04, the older AMD drivers were deprecated in favor of the newer open source ones from AMD.

Ubuntu 16.10 has the newer kernel (v4.8) and thus has better graphics support for AMD out of the box. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with kernel v4.4.

Alternatively, you can install the latest kernel from Ubuntu's mainline kernel PPA - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and remove nomodeset from grub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, the upgrade didn't solve this for me, and it seems to be behaving the same in regard to the graphics situation as it was before.